# Discord.js. Embed messages problems

Tags: node.js

When I try this code it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Is the code wrong? Please help, I am very new to node.js.

```
 switch(args[0]){
        case 'embed':
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            function userInfo(user, msg){
            addField('Player Name', message.author.username);
            msg.channel.sendEmbed(embed);}
            break;
```

Comment: what is an error message?

Answer (score 0):

The method  `msg.channel.sendEmbed(embed);}` - wrong

You need use:

```
msg.channel.send(embed)
```

And whats doing your `fuction userInfo(user, msg)` ? I think it is not necessary

if you have 2 or more `case` blocks, and try constant embed in each, you must got error `" Identifier 'Embed' has already been declared"`

At the last in fist part of code you use **msg**, when you try to add field you use **message**. According to the provided code, it is not clear which variable you previously defined (**msg** or **message**), so you will need to change it yourself.

This solution should work if the previous part of the code is written correctly.

```
 switch(args[0]){
     const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        case 'embed':
            embed.addField('Player Name', msg.author.username);
            msg.channel.send(embed);
            break;
```